# How to do live replication of few tables in sql server database?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How I can do live replication of few tables in SQL Server?

The reason why I would like to achieve this is so that I can run SQL Statements on those tables without worrying about the table being locked

Comment: Have you read up on transactional replication?

Comment: Nope, but certainly going to do so now. Thanks Nic

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest start at

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179855.aspx

This link gives detailed steps for implementing replication

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/715550/SQL-Server-Replication-Step-by-Step